# This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully VS2017 Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just got started with XAMARIN today.I have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition v15.7.6.I downloaded XAMARIN from Visual Studio Installer :
[image]

I started VS,navigated to **Tools>Options>Xamarin>Android Settings** and made sure that JDK,Android SDK and NDK locations are correct.But whenever i create a new project(Template is : **Android App(Xamarin)**) and i open(or navigate to) **Resources>Layout>activity_main.axml** , the designer shows an error at the bottom saying :

> The project contains resources that might not be affected,rendering might be affected

[image]

I have no clue why this is happening even after everything was installed properly.If i make any changes to the `.axml` file, the UI is not updated and when i try to debug the app(through emulator), all i get is a blank emulator screen.
[image]

I am totally new to Xamarin so please help me out by guiding me or pointing out where/what i missed ?

Comment: This is just warning you can ignore it.

Comment: I am also a new user, but even with the warning sign/banner, apps still run properly for me. I have tried searching everywhere for a solution, because the warning is still annoying, but it seems no one has a solution :(Someone suggested cleaning and rebuilding the project, but that didn't work for me. 
If you did manage to fix this already, please let me know.

Comment: same problem. Noone knows the answer yet? the app runs but it is difficult to set the controls because you cannot see how are you placing them

Comment: I am using VS 2019 now and the warning pops up sometimes. However, the designer is now workable as it shows everything properly.

Comment: Still exists in latest VS2019 (16.3.8). Usual unprofessional and lazy Microsoft coding standard.

Comment: @Gwynge, yes the problem exists. But actually, you don't need the designer. It's not fluent. Rather use Android Studio for the designing and just copy-paste the xml code.